# Error when calling function within array of its own prototype (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm just experimenting and don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
var MyFunc = function() {};                                                    

MyFunc.prototype = {                                                           
  receive: function() {                                                        
    console.log("Received");                                                   
  },                                                                           
  spine: [MyFunc],                                                             
}                                                                              

var func = new MyFunc();                                                       

func.receive();          //works                                               
func.spine[0].receive(); //error: Object function () {} has no method 'receive'
```

The last line is the error line.

Full output:

```
Received

/home/zxcv/Documents/CODE/js/stuff/gp/scratch.js:13
func.spine[0].receive(); //error: Object function () {} has no method 'receive
              ^
TypeError: Object function () {} has no method 'receive'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/USER/Documents/CODE/js/stuff/gp/scratch.js:13:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3

shell returned 8
```

Comment: Because at the time of assignment myFunc is still only a function with no inherited method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `spine[0]` is MyFunc (the constructor function object), not an instance object of MyFunc. Functions defined in `prototype` get put on the instances created by the constructor not on the constructor itself.

You would have go through the prototype in order to execute the function

```
func.spine[0].prototype.receive();
```

If you were wanting to create a method that you could execute directly from MyFunc you would need to actually define it on MyFunc

```
MyFunc.receive2 = function(){
    console.log("Received");
};
var func = new MyFunc();
func.spine[0].receive2();
//Or
MyFunc.receive2();

//Note you would not be able to call this directly from the instance
func.receive2(); //would cause an error
```